# System of two nonhomogenous ODE - is my solution correct

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

$$x' = y$$
$$y' = x+e^t + e^{-t}$$

We need to solve it by reducing it to one second order ODE. Here's what I id.

1. I derived the first equation w.r.t.    $t$

$$x''= y'$$

2. Plugged in y' from the second equation to get

$$x'' = x+e^t+e^{-t}$$

Which is $$x'' - x = e^t + e^{-t}$$

The solution to this ode is $$C_1e^t + C_2e^{-t} - \frac{1}{2}e^{-t}t + \frac{1}{2}e^tt$$

This is x. As per the first equation, to get $y$, I need to take the derivative of $x$ which is

$$x' = y = C_1e^t - C_2e^{-t} + \frac{1}{2}e^t(t+1) - \frac{1}{2}e^{-t}(1-t)$$

The last two expressions are my solutions. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct.